# Switch workspace in activities overview

Tags: 20.04, workspaces, activities-overview, mouse-wheel

There is a nifty feature in Ubuntu 20.04's Activities overview where users can switch to next/previous workspace by scrolling the mouse wheel.

If I scroll one "click" down on the mouse wheel, it goes to the next workspace. I wait a bit and scroll down one more "click" and again, it goes to the next workspace.

If I quickly scroll multiple "click"s down on the mouse wheel, it only goes to the next workspace.

How can I quickly scroll multiple "click"s down on the mouse wheel and have it scroll to the next nth workspace, depending on how many "click"s it went through?

Comment: Mainly this is based on only assumption, but I found this: https://sources.debian.org/src/gnome-shell/3.38.2-1/js/ui/workspacesView.js/ To me it seems that `SCROLL_TIMEOUT_TIME`'s value is hardcoded to 150 milliseconds. In other words, that's the minimum time gap between accepted scroll events. I agree, frustrating. Either you find a way to override this file on your system (unlikely? but pls let me know if you manage to, I'm interested in that too), or you find an existing gnome shell extension that does something to this limit, or you learn to write gnome shell extensions yourself... :|

Comment: I got an idea. Maybe they implemented this speed limit to ensure sufficient time for the graphics "department" to render these workspaces. Again, just an assumption.